# Sort list into list based on common string while keeping entire list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that sorta looks like the following:

```
old_data = [[0,0,0,X],[1,0,0,A],[2,0,0,HJ],[3,0,0,X],[4,0,0,A],[5,0,0,K],[6,0,0,K]
```

I want to be able to sort the lists into their own seperate lists which would like the following:

```
X_list = [[0,0,0,X],[3,0,0,X]]
A_list = [[1,0,0,A],[4,0,0,A]]
HJ_list = [[2,0,0,HJ]]
K_list = [[5,0,0,K],[6,0,0,K]]
```

I tried playing around with a few features in pandas and some other solutions on stack, however, they all group the specific value into one list, which ends up deleting all the other data in the list. Furthermore, there will be an X amount of list[3], therefore it will need to generate X amount of lists. The previous thing I tried was this:

```
values = sorted(set(map(lambda x: x[3], old_data)))
newlist = [[y[3] for y in old_data if y[3] == x] for x in values]
```

which outputs, something as follows:

```
newlist = [[X,X],[A,A],[HG],[K,K]]
```

Possibly if there was someway to rearrange the code above maybe to keep all the data and create an X amount of lists with a for loop? I don't really understand the code above, so I couldn't figure out how to do it. Otherwise, possibly some way using pandas?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
old_data = [[0,0,0,'X'],
            [1,0,0,'A'],
            [2,0,0,'HJ'],
            [3,0,0,'X'],
            [4,0,0,'A'],
            [5,0,0,'K'],
            [6,0,0,'K']]

{k: list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(old_data, key=lambda x: x[-1]), lambda x: x[-1])}
```

output:

```
{'A': [[1, 0, 0, 'A'], [4, 0, 0, 'A']],
 'HJ': [[2, 0, 0, 'HJ']],
 'K': [[5, 0, 0, 'K'], [6, 0, 0, 'K']],
 'X': [[0, 0, 0, 'X'], [3, 0, 0, 'X']]}
```

and if you want a custom group name:

```
{k+'_list': list(v)
 for k,v in groupby(sorted(old_data, key=lambda x: x[-1]),
lambda x: x[-1])}
```

```
{'A_list': [[1, 0, 0, 'A'], [4, 0, 0, 'A']],
 'HJ_list': [[2, 0, 0, 'HJ']],
 'K_list': [[5, 0, 0, 'K'], [6, 0, 0, 'K']],
 'X_list': [[0, 0, 0, 'X'], [3, 0, 0, 'X']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your A,X etc are strings, we can make a dict, with the keys as your labels, and the values as your lists.

We loop over your data, and use the `.setdefault` method to mkae an empty list for any keys we havent seen yet. Then we append your list on

```
old_data = [[0,0,0,'X'],[1,0,0,'A'],[2,0,0,'HJ'],[3,0,0,'X'],[4,0,0,'A'],[5,0,0,'K'],[6,0,0,'K']]

output = {}
for i in old_data:
    output.setdefault(i[3]+'_list', []).append(i)
output

{'X_list': [[0, 0, 0, 'X'], [3, 0, 0, 'X']],
 'A_list': [[1, 0, 0, 'A'], [4, 0, 0, 'A']],
 'HJ_list': [[2, 0, 0, 'HJ']],
 'K_list': [[5, 0, 0, 'K'], [6, 0, 0, 'K']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Series` from your list of lists and then use `groupby` to split them based on the last element.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(old_data)
s.groupby(s.str[-1]).agg(list)
```

---

```
A     [[1, 0, 0, A], [4, 0, 0, A]]
HJ                 [[2, 0, 0, HJ]]
K     [[5, 0, 0, K], [6, 0, 0, K]]
X     [[0, 0, 0, X], [3, 0, 0, X]]
dtype: object
```